# 'onclick' function not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

The following is the jsp page that I created:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Start</title>

    <link href="resources/css/StartPage.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="options">
        <label class="label">Name of Excel File
        <select name="filename" id="selectfile" class="active">
            <option selected disabled>---select---</option>
                    <c:forEach var="file" items="${exportedfiles}">
                        <option value="${file}"><c:out value="${file}"/></option>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <option value="custom">New file</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="filename" id="fileinput"/>
        </label>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="button" id="editbutton" onclick="editExcel()"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                function editExcel(){
                    var filename;
                    var pageURL;
                    var select = document.getElementById("selectfile");
                    var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                    if(select.value == "custom"){
                        filename = input.value;
                        pageURL = "addTestCase";
                    }
                    else{
                        filename = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                        pageURL = "import";
                    }
                    console.log(pageURL);
                window.location.href = pageURL+"?filename="+filename;
                }

                var editExcel = function(event){
                        var filename;
                        var pageURL;
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectfile");
                        var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                        if(select.value == "custom"){
                            filename = input.value;
                            pageURL = "addTestCase";
                        }
                        else{
                            filename = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                            pageURL = "import";
                        }
                        console.log(pageURL);
                    window.location.href = pageURL+"?filename="+filename;
                }

                var takeInput = function(event){
                    var val = event.target.value;
                    var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                    var button = document.getElementById("editbutton");
                    if(val == 'custom'){
                        input.style.display = "block";
                        event.target.style.display = "none";
                        input.className = "active";
                        event.target.className = "";
                        button.value = "Create";
                    }
                    else{
                        input.style.display = "none";
                        event.target.style.display = "block";
                        input.className = "";
                        event.target.className = "active";
                        button.value = "Edit";
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById("selectfile").onchange = takeInput;
                document.getElementById("selectfile").addEventListener('change',takeInput,true);
                document.getElementById("editbutton").onclick = editExcel;
                document.getElementById("editbutton").addEventListener('click',editExcel,true);

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

On clicking the "editbutton", the browser should navigate to the URL that is generated in editExcel().However, the function is never called.

Apart from adding an event listener to "editbutton" in javascript and defining the 'onclick' attribute within the tag, I have tried moving the script block to within the head block and also tried changing onclick to onClick. None of these tricks seem to work.

Similar javascript code works for other navigation buttons in my application. So I believe the 'onclick' event is never generated.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: check your browser console to seee whether there are any errors

Comment: The function is being called chk by adding alert message inside function.

Comment: Why are you write function definition twice in script code ?

Comment: I was trying different ways of calling the function. I have also tried adding an alert message but that doesn't appear.

Comment: try to close " function editExcel(){" at the end of javascript so that all vars be in one single Function

Comment: i.e.     function editExcel(){                  ........                                                var editExcel = function(event){                                                                    ...               }                                                                                          var takeInput = function(event){  ... }                                                                                                                      }

Comment: The console doesn't show any request being passed when the button is clicked. No errors either.

Comment: Try using Ajax since you have multiple event listeners in your code.

Comment: @srikanthr That didn't work either.

Comment: Here's what you're trying to do in very simple terms... works fine. http://fiddle.jshell.net/jmk13p95/  I'd recommend getting the simplest thing possible working and then add the other stuff back in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Start</title>

    <link href="resources/css/StartPage.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="options">
        <label class="label">Name of Excel File
        <select name="filename" id="selectfile" class="active">
            <option selected disabled>---select---</option>
                    <c:forEach var="file" items="${exportedfiles}">
                        <option value="${file}"><c:out value="${file}"/></option>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <option value="custom">New file</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="filename" id="fileinput"/>
        </label>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="button" id="editbutton" onclick="editExcel()"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                function editExcel(){
                alert("asdd");
                    var filename;
                    var pageURL;
                    var select = document.getElementById("selectfile");
                    var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                    if(select.value == "custom"){
                        filename = input.value;
                        pageURL = "addTestCase";
                    }
                    else{
                        filename = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                        pageURL = "import";
                    }
                    console.log(pageURL);
                window.location.href = pageURL+"?filename="+filename;

                     var editExcel = function(event){
                            var filename;
                            var pageURL;
                            var select = document.getElementById("selectfile");
                            var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                            if(select.value == "custom"){
                                filename = input.value;
                                pageURL = "addTestCase";
                            }
                            else{
                                filename = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                                pageURL = "import";
                            }
                            console.log(pageURL);
                        window.location.href = pageURL+"?filename="+filename;
                    }
                     var takeInput = function(event){
                    var val = event.target.value;
                    var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
                    var button = document.getElementById("editbutton");
                    if(val == 'custom'){
                        input.style.display = "block";
                        event.target.style.display = "none";
                        input.className = "active";
                        event.target.className = "";
                        button.value = "Create";
                    }
                    else{
                        input.style.display = "none";
                        event.target.style.display = "block";
                        input.className = "";
                        event.target.className = "active";
                        button.value = "Edit";
                    }
                }
                }

                document.getElementById("selectfile").onchange = takeInput;
                document.getElementById("selectfile").addEventListener('change',takeInput,true);
                document.getElementById("editbutton").onclick = editExcel;
                document.getElementById("editbutton").addEventListener('click',editExcel,true);

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this :-
          But still i insist you to use AJAX when you have multiple event handlers for the sake of efficient working

Answer (score 0):

The original code is working now.I changed a few values in the style sheet for the #editbutton and it worked!I still haven't figured out what the problem was though, because when I reverted back to the original values the button was still working. Here's the CSS file:

```
#content{
    background:#2A88AD;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#content label{
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    left:40%;
    top:30%;
    width:20%;
    height:5%;
    font: bold 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

select{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    font:500 17px Arial #000;
}

#selectfile *{
    background-color:transparent;
    font:500 17px Arial #fff;
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
}

#fileinput {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}

#editbutton{
    position:fixed;
    left:40%;
    top:55%;
    width:20%;
    height:5%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: #2A88AD;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    border: 1px solid #257C9E;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#editbutton:hover{
    color:#00B8E6;
}

.options{
    z-index: 2;
    position:fixed;
    left:40%;
    top:35%;
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
}

.options .active{
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```